# Handling PDFs files on special websites with a "quick view" option with CEFSharp

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

With CEFsharp I want to have the option of either allowing the PDF plugin to show the PDF or to have the file downloaded and shown with the default PDF program installed on the PC.

To show in a default PDF program  I am using the `CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-pdf-extension", "1")` command and implementing the downloadhandler interface.  To show pdfs in the plugin I do not set the command `CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-pdf-extension", "1")` which in turn means that the download handler is not called.

There is a website which has some kind of file quickview feature.  This means that it has a panel in which it shows the file.  The problem is that with `CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-pdf-extension", "1")` then the websites panel is left empty and the PDF is downloaded through the downloadhandler.

I can tell as early as OnBeforeBrowse (through the URL) that the website is attempting to show the pdf in a panel and of course see the MIME type in the OnBeforeResourceLoad and OnResourceResponse.

My question is how can I get the my browser to use the default plugin in this case?

The only solution I can think of is to not set `CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-pdf-extension", "1")` thereby allowing this special quickview feature to work.  However if I want all other PDFs to be shown in the default PDF program I need to intercept a PDF download (for example in the OnBeforeBrowse) and download it with the help of other .NET assemblies like HTTPWebRequest.  The problem with this method is I need to collect and send cookies and it feels like a hack that will not last if the website changes.

Comment: You can try http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestContextHandler_OnBeforePluginLoad.htm

Comment: Thanks. Setting the PluginPolicy to disable would stop the loading of the default pdf viewer but leaves me still wtih getting the pdf with cookies and credentials etc. My understanding is that CefSharp does not implement the CefURLRequest classes.  Is the only solution then to use an IResponseFilter to get the PDF file?

Comment: It's one of those situations that requires tinkering to get all the use cases working, so I can only make general suggestions. You can probably cancel downloading of the PDF in OnBeforeBrowse then call StartDownload, search the API doc for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a highly unique situation however I will explain my experience. Whilst this is also probably more a website issue it may help you with your CefSharp code.

1. I did not disable the pdf viewer. This means that all PDF's will render in a browser window.
2. If I choose to want my PDF to automatically open with the default PDF application then I check the response objects MIMEType of "application/pdf" in the [OnResourceResponse Method](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnResourceResponse.htm).
3. I then call [StartDownload](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_StartDownload.htm) on the URL which provided the response.

**Tinkering - Issues I Found**
Starting a download opened up a whole new set of issues. The first is that new requests and responses are made after you call startdownload which means you can get stuck in a loop of continually downloading the same file. In my case all PDFs are created by a PopUp window so in the LifeSpanHandler I create a new ChromiumBrowser and with this newly created browser I had my IRequestHandler to wait for the MIMEType as indicated in 2 above. I then called startDownload on the IBrowser of my main browser.  This meant that the actual download will happen on the main browser and a different instance of the RequestHandler.

I also saw many examples where people just check for a ".pdf" in the URL in the BeforeBrowse event and then download the file while being able to also cancel the browse. I could not do this as the website did not even have PDF in the URL. The first time I could tell the content was in the Response. One thing I have not achieved is how to cancel something at this (Response) stage. There is a question here in StackOverflow (could not find it now) which discusses setting the URL to either "" (no string) or a fake domain. I have not tested this and have no idea if this saves time.